# Limiting outbound traffic to AWS Management Console or other Amazon consoles

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, firewall, whitelist, traffic-management

I've a network whose outbound traffic is strictly limited to a whitelist of sites or domains. I searched and couldn't find any documentation about how could I allow stations on this network to use AWS Management Console without allowing any arbitrary outgoing connections.

Is there any minimal list of hostnames, domains or IP ranges - similar to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/azure-portal-safelist-urls - that I'd whitelist for this purpose?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[This is the list of AWS IP ranges](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/aws-ip-ranges.html) which can be filtered by region.

As for domains, you're going to have a tough time whitelisting everything, unless you use a very restricted set of services. Example:

```
console.aws.amazon.com
[your region].console.aws.amazon.com
signin.aws.amazon.com
support.aws.amazon.com
s3.console.aws.amazon.com
aws.amazon.com
docs.aws.amazon.com
forums.aws.amazon.com
status.aws.amazon.com
aws-portal.amazon.com
... etc ...
```

You would need a [zone transfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_zone_transfer) to actually get a full list of subdomains, something like `dig @server.com zone.com axfr` — but this also would be brittle, if AWS's DNS servers even allow it (they probably don't).

Comment: Zac, thanks for the info, the problem is, though, that I'm looking for a way to open access to AWS native services, like the Console - while avoiding opening it to services of AWS tenants, which, as I understand, might be placed in the same ranges or under the same domains as AWS own ones.